# How can i make a previous button for my music player using React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Im making a music player which grabs the songs from a firebase project, in the music player I created a next button that grabs a random id from firebase project but I don't know how to approach the button that takes the user back to the previous song. please how would I approach this

```js
interface Song {
  artist: string;
  artworkURL: string;
  audioURL: string;
  comments: [];
  owner: string;
  title: string;
}

const PlaySong = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const [song, setSong] = useState<Song | null>(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [previouslyPlayed, setPreviouslyPlayed] = useState([Song])
  const [showComments, setShowComments] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!id) return;

    Songs.findById(id).then((fetchedSong: Song) => setSong(fetchedSong));
  }, [id]);

  const handlePlay: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  const playedSong =() => {
    Songs.getRandomSong().then((randomSong) => setPlayedIds(randomSong));
  }
 
  const handlePrev: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) =>{
    
  }

  const handleNext: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) => {
    Songs.getRandomSong().then((randomSong) => setSong(randomSong));
  };
```

Comment: 1. maintain a state something like `const [playedIds, setPlayedIds] = useState([])`, 2. Push playing song to this state array every time you jump to a new song, (from `handleNext` or `handlePlay`) 3. When going back pop from the array, and play it

Comment: thanks Nishant, how would i push a song to the new state made

Comment: `setPlayedIds([...playedIds, currentlyPlayingId]`

Comment: i am kinda of lost on what to do I tried this `const [playedIds, setPlayedIds] = useState([ Song])` `if (isPlaying){
    const playedSong = playedIds;  
  }
 
  const handlePrev: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) =>{
    playedSong().then((Songs) => setPlayedIds(Songs));
  }`

Comment: No, no. It seems like you need to brush up React fundamentals. You start with empty array (as there is no song played yet), then in the function that handles switching to the next song, you need to update this array with the song id that was currently playing. In handlePrev, you just get the last element from the array, and update the state that manages the array with a new shorter array that does not have the last element.

Comment: thanks mate i really do just started learning React this is my first project, btw the song is being called from firebase, I updated the code to show the "song" array I'm trying to call

Comment: i thought of it and want to try - " When a user clicks the next button store the old song in state called [previouslyPlayed, setPreviouslyPlayed]. Then use array.filter to the filter that state to get the song played just before"